# Howto include ExtentReport link in JUnit Report

Tags: java, selenium, junit, extentreports

I have added ExtentReports to our Selenium/Java/TestNG framework. However our company Build Pipeline uses the JUnit Report. I have saved the ExtentReports.html as an artifact, which I can get to, but it takes a bunch of clicks and users don't care to do that. I would like to include a html link to the ExtentReport on the JUnit Report Page. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: If you use the HTML publisher plugin, the report will be placed on the build opening page. Just 1 click needed then

Comment: Thanks, but that looks to be Jenkins specific. The company I work with doesn't use it. Is there an alternate solution you can suggest?

Comment: What CI do you use?  One way is to use a post-build script that replaces the junit report in lieu of the one created from Extent OR edit the junit report to include a link instead.  I would be more comfortable doing #2 even though the process is a little convoluted. My users may scream at me for changing something that they've been more comfortable with.  :)

Comment: @foursyth I agree I need a script. I was hoping there was a Junit API call to insert a link in the report. We are using a customized Ant build. I manually edited the html file and gave a link to my report, works fine. Using TestNG could I run when a script of AfterTest or would it need to be inserted in the Ant target...